# UISearchController is appearing into nextView with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I have implemented a simple `UISearchController` into my `UITableViewController` programatically. And below is my complete code:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    let appleProducts = ["Mac","iPhone","Apple Watch","iPad"]
    var filteredAppleProducts = [String]()
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if (self.resultSearchController.active){
            return self.filteredAppleProducts.count
        }else{
            return self.appleProducts.count
        }
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell?

        if (self.resultSearchController.active)
        {
            cell!.textLabel?.text = self.filteredAppleProducts[indexPath.row]

            return cell!
        }
        else
        {
            cell!.textLabel?.text = self.appleProducts[indexPath.row]

            return cell!
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Detail") as! DetailViewController
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController){

        self.filteredAppleProducts.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
        let array = (self.appleProducts as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        self.filteredAppleProducts = array as! [String]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

My `resultSearchController` is working completely fine but when I click on any cell then `UISearchController` is appearing into my next view too as shown into below image:

[image]

But my Second view is empty.

how I can remove this `resultSearchController` when I switch to another view so it will not appear into next view?

Project [Sample](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=61705492921836081074) for more Info.

Comment: see this link my friend http://programmingthomas.com/blog/2014/10/5/uisearchcontroller-and-definespresentationcontext

Comment: Thank you for the link. @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one line in `viewDidLoad`

```
 self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

Doc

> A Boolean value that indicates whether this view controller's view is covered when the view controller or one of its descendants presents a view controller.

GIF

[image]